# Google Play Map API won´t work with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-maps

I uploaded apk map app to google play store but it won´t show google map. I did everything I think I have to do but apparently forgot something. App shows the map white with google logo on right bottom.

I´m using Android Studio 1.02 version.

1. Did the key file (.jks)
2. Used keystore command and got the SHA code and added to google api account.
3. Copied the API KEY to apps google_maps_api.xml
4. Added following data to gradle app file

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 21
       buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "fi.xxxx"
           minSdkVersion 14
           targetSdkVersion 21
           versionCode 6
           versionName "1.0"
       }
       signingConfigs {
           release {
               storeFile file("xxx.jks")
               storePassword "xxx"
               keyAlias "xxx"
               keyPassword "xxx"
           }
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
               signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   5. Map still won´t work.
   6. Map works with other api key and I managed to debug the app it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Go to console.developers.google.com
2. Create a new project
3. In the sidebar under **APIs and Auth** select **APIs**
4. Scroll down till you see **Google Maps Android API v2** and switch it on by clicking the **off**  button.
5. In the sidebar under **APIs and Auth** select **Credentials**
6. Click **Create new key** under **Public API access**
7. Select **Android Key**
8. Paste the SHA code in the box along with the package name of your app like this

> SHA_KEY;PACKAGE_NAME

9. Click create then copy the API key.
10. Open you AndroidManifest.xml and add this line

    ```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY" />
    ```
11. Compile and run the app now

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. So API key always needs a new project if you want to publish an app? Or what went wrong with my stuff?

Comment: I think since you copied the API key to the wrong file it wasn't working. While releasing the app use the SHA of the signature you used to sign the app. Get the new API key and replace it with the old. If I helped you helped help other by marking this question solved. Never post your API key its for your use